# Parameter inside of comparable (Java)

Tags: java, comparable

```
public int comareTo(Employee e) {
    if (this.wage > e.wage) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(this.wage < e.wage) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the comparable method that I wrote inside of the Employee class. It is inside an employee class and it is meant to compare the wage of two employees. Is this a legitimate comparable method, or does the parameter have to be of type object. If yes, why does it have to be of type object?

Thanks!

Comment: Try and add the annotation `@Override` above the method and see what the compiler says ;)

Comment: We need to see the class declaration to tell you if this is a correct override.

Comment: Tangentially -- a one-line alternative to the method body: [`return Integer.compare(this.wage, other.wage)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)).

Answer (score 1):

Using a subclass of the `Object` class (e.g. `Employee`) is fine. However as Jigar Joshi suggests in his answer, `compareTo` should always return the numerical difference, not just `{-1,0,1}`. This way a collection of `Employee` instances can be easily sorted.

Comment: Would generics then every be necessary in this case? Since we can always specify that it is an employee

Comment: No, if you will always be comparing instances of `Employee`, there is no need to complicate this any further.

Comment: If this class implements (properly) `Comparable<Employee>` then you're right, but if he used raw-type, he might get RunTimeException!

Comment: The class is not Comparable<Employee>. I've only implemented Comparable. Why would this not work?

Answer (score 1):

if you specify type parameter while declaraing implementation then you don't need Object, you could use specific type

this is not proper implementation of comparission, it should return how much greater an employee is compare to other, instead of 1, 0, -1

Comment: Can you please provide reference (docs) to the second sentence ?

Comment: well it is correct, I am saying that it is better to return how much greater/lesser employee is in comparission

Comment: I don't think comparable is supposed to return how much greater, just whether its greater or not.

Comment: According to [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) it's good enough to return [-1,0,1]. As long as the the comparison stays transitive and symmetric - it's good.

Comment: As for your question "why an int?" - because boolean cannot return 3 different states.

Comment: *"it should return how much greater an employee is compare to other, instead of 1, 0, -1"* Unless `wage` is `short` or `char`, this is an impossible requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If in your class header, you specify

`implements Comparable<Employee>`

then your compareTo method is fine.

Incidentally, you can shorten the code to:

`public int comareTo(Employee e) {
    return Integer.signum(this.wage - e.wage);
}`

Comment: Why do I have to specify implements Comparable <Employee> ?

Comment: @aaa You don;t need to, but it removes some messy casting in the compareTo method and makes it clear that you only intend comparing employee instances.

Comment: But even if I don't have it, doesn't the parameter specify that it needs to be an employee. Therefore it would be impossible for anyone to put in anything other than an employee, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it would, but the method would not implement Comparable(Object). As suggested earlier, add the @Override annotation and see what the IDE/compiler tells you - either you need casts, or specify the generic implements syntax..